# Redim (declared?) variable when setting to AS NEW

Tags: vb.net

Hey all I've been trying to find some resources on how to go about doing this but am unable to find anything since, really, i do not know really what it would be called in the first place.

The code in question is this:

```
Dim updateCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, myCONN)
```

There are a few places that i need to use that over that's inside an IF THEN structure.

However, when i dim it outside the IF THEN structure then it tells me (inside the IF THEN) that its not declared.

So the full example is this:

```
If alreadyCreatedSettingsTable = False Then
   Dim updateCmd As New SqlCommand(sql, myCONN)

   updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@urlLink", SqlDbType.VarChar)
End If

rssItems = rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item")

For i = 0 To rssItems.Count - 1
   rssDetail = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("link")

   If rssDetail.Equals(Nothing) = False Then
      rssLink = rssDetail.InnerText.Trim
      updateCmd.Parameters("@urlLink").Value = rssLink
   End If
etc....
```

The **If alreadyCreatedSettingsTable = False Then** dim works just fine for the **updateCmd.Parameters.Add** but when its inside the **For i = 0 To rssItems.Count - 1** that is where it tells me its not decalired.

How can i use that anywhere no matter what and reDim it?

I've tried

```
Dim updateCmd
```

But i then do not know how to set **As New SqlCommand(sql, myCONN)** since its already been Dim'ed already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dim` declares a variable. `As New` is just syntactic sugar; the scope of the variable is inside that `If` block. Declare it outside and initialize it inside:

```
Dim updateCmd As SqlCommand

If alreadyCreatedSettingsTable = False Then
   sql = "UPDATE jotSettings " & _
                        "etc etc...."

   updateCmd = New SqlCommand(sql, myCONN)

   updateCmd.Parameters.Add("@urlLink", SqlDbType.VarChar)
End If

rssItems = rssDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item")

For i = 0 To rssItems.Count - 1
   rssDetail = rssItems.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("link")

   If rssDetail.Equals(Nothing) = False Then
      rssLink = rssDetail.InnerText.Trim
      updateCmd.Parameters("@urlLink").Value = rssLink
   End If
```

Also, please *never* write `= False`; use `Not` instead. Or, in the case of `rssDetail.Equals(Nothing) = False`, you almost certainly want `rssDetail IsNot Nothing` instead.

Finally, as written, this is pointless. If `alreadyCreatedSettingsTable` is `True`, you'll get a `NullReferenceException` when you use `updateCmd.Parameters("@urlLink")`. It seems to me that it's something that should be declared outside of a loop, or at class level - though that's just a guess.

P.S. Why are you overwriting `updateCmd.Parameters("@urlLink")` every time? That's wasteful.

Comment: Isn't `updateCmd` going to be Nothing if `alreadyCreatedSettingsTable` is true, and therefore get an error accessing `updateCmd.Parameters` in the for loop?

Comment: Thanks for the help @minitech and lc. The code above was for example purposes only just to illustrate my point. Sadly i have -2 points now because of it...